# Specify linux interface for docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

Is it somehow possible to specify which linux network interface a docker container should use? I have multiple interfaces and want to use different ones for different containers.

From what I can read I am able to configure the default docker bridge, but I am not able to use a couple of different bridges for the docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of answering your question.

Typically, containers are provisioned on internal "private" networks, and services are exposed via port mapping.  Using this mechanism, you can expose services on different interfaces simply by specifying different ip addresses to the `-p` option.  For example, if your host has:

- eth0 at 192.168.10.10
- eth1 at 192.168.20.20

You can expose services on `eth0` like this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.10.10:80:80 httpd mywebserver
```

And on eth1 like this:

```
docker run -p 192.168.20.20:5432:5432 postgres mydatabaseserver
```

In most cases, this is what you want.

It is technically possible to connect containers directly to your physical interfaces, but the process requires manual intervention (even with the enhanced support for multiple container networks in Docker 1.9).

Comment: I need to be able to control outgoing connections as well.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to provide a specific example of what you wish to accomplish? That will make it easier to provide answers that solve your actual requirements.